# Wordpress page suddenly blank

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a WordPress website that's been running for almost two years now. All of a sudden, it started to show a blank page on any public page. The admin part on `/wp-admin` is still working without any problems.

A http request is successful (status 200), but the returned content is completely empty (not even an  tag).

I'm not really a PHP/WP expert. A simple web search got a lot of results, but mostly old stuff and never any clear conclusion of the problem's source, i.e. how to fix it. I already enabled `WP_DEBUG` in wp-config.php, but this only shows debug messages in wp-admin, but the public page remains blank.

Where should I continue searching?

The problematic website is http://lolkitten.org/.

**Update**

I just found `index.php` inside my `public_html`, which was empty. After writing something into it, it appears on my home page! Also, there's a directory `/home/<user>/home/<user>/public_html/` which looks like complete nonsense to me.

**Update 2**

The Problem solved itself after upgrading to Wordpress 3.8. I don't know why, but it seems like some files (like index.php) were messed up and got replaced by fresh ones in this update.

**Possible solution / workaround**

I've had this problem again. This time, my `index.php` was completely empty. In my dashboard, under *Dashboard > Updates*, I clicked on *Re-install Now* and it fixed itself.

Comment: Probably a PHP error; can you enable logging/display of PHP errors and see if that leads anywhere?

Comment: Like @mc10 said, enable PHP errors by putting this at the top of your page: `<?php ini_set('display_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); ?>`

Comment: Check for closing `?>` tags. There shouldn't be space/new line after a closing `?>`

Comment: Super weird error, I can confirm that creating an index.php file in your theme or child_theme directory fixes it

Answer (score 3):

Most likely the `wp-content` folder can’t be found. When you login to the admin does it state that the templates can’t be found in red text in the center of the page right when you login?

I recommend going into your `wp-config.php` and adjust—or add—the following constants:

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://lolkitten.org');
define('WP_HOME',    'http://lolkitten.org');
define('WP_CONTENT_DIR', '/path/to/your/wp-content');
define('WP_CONTENT_URL', 'http://lolkitten.org/wp-content');
```

Fairly confident that the key to fixing this will be the `WP_CONTENT_DIR` setting. You need the full path to the directory in the file system to your `wp-content` folder.  So if you have a standard Unix setup with `lolkitten.org` in it’s own directory that path would be:

```
/var/www/lolkitten.org/wp-content
```

And the `WP_CONTENT_DIR` value would be:

```
define('WP_CONTENT_DIR', '/var/www/lolkitten.org/wp-content');
```

**EDIT** Adding info on how to determine your script’s absolute path if you do not have SSH access to the server, but have FTP access of some sort. Just FTP to the server & create a test file called `test.php` and just put the following code in it:

```
<?php
  echo dirname(__FILE__);
?>
```

Now load that into your browser to get the full path:

```
http://lolkitten.org/test.php
```

[`__FILE__` is a magic constant](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) in PHP that will echo the full/absolute path of a PHP script.

Answer (score 0):

try deactivatinhg all the plugin once.
And if you can not access admin panel do the following to deactivate plugins
In the database - wp_options table

change the entry to `a:0:{}` on `option ID 35- active_plugins`

Comment: I just deactivated all plugins at once (19 of them), but nothing changed. Is there some Wordpress-cache I need to flush?

Answer (score -1):

As far as i see error, it is because of **share-buttons** plugin.

Try removing share-buttons plugin from plugin folder and then check again.

If still problem exists then remove all active plugins and check again.

I too had same issue and it was because of plugin. I deactivated plugins one by one and my site was recovered from crash.